# Compatibility conditions for Yetter-Drinfeld modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

In [the paper](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~laugwitz/2010-08%20-%20Yetter-Drinfeld%20and%20Hopf%20Modules%20-%20Bachelorarbeit.pdf), page 28, Definition 4.2.1, the compatibility condition for a Yetter-Drinfeld module over $H$ is 
$$
h_{(1)} v_{(-1)} \otimes h_{(2)}.v_{(0)} = (h_{(1)}.v)_{(-1)}h_{(2)} \otimes (h_{(1)}.v)_{(0)}, v \in V, h \in H.
$$ 
On the other hand, in [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yetter%E2%80%93Drinfeld_category#Definition), the compatibility condition for a Yetter-Drinfeld module over $H$ is 
$$
\delta(h.v) = h_{(1)} v_{(-1)} S(h_{(3)}) \otimes h_{(2)}.v_{(0)}, v \in V, h \in H.
$$ 
Are the two conditions equivalent? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the second equation holds. Then 
\begin{align*}
\delta(h_{1}.v)=(h_{1}. v)_{-1}\otimes(h_{1}.v)_{0}=h_{1,1}v_{-1}Sh_{1,3}\otimes h_{1,2}. v_{0}
\end{align*}
and therefore
$$
(h_{1}.v)_{-1}h_{2}\otimes(h_{1}.v)_{0}=h_{1,1}v_{-1}Sh_{1,3}h_{2}\otimes h_{1,2}.v_{0}=h_{1}v_{-1}\otimes h_{2}.v_{0}.
$$
Conversely, assume that the first equation holds. Then
\begin{align*}
        (m\otimes &id)(h_{11}v_{-1}\otimes Sh_2\otimes(h_{12}.v_0) )\\  
        &=(m\otimes id)\left( (h_{11}.v)_{-1}h_{12}\otimes Sh_2\otimes (h_{11}. v)_0 \right)\\
        &=(h_1.v)_{-1}h_2Sh_3\otimes (h_1.v)_0\\
        &=(h.v)_{-1}\otimes (h.v)_0.
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you very much. Why $ h_{1,1}v_{−1}Sh_{1,3}h_2 \otimes h_{1,2}.v_0=h_1 v_{−1} \otimes h_2.v_0 $?

Comment: Because S is the antipode.

Comment: Use the coassociativity, we have $$ h_{11} v_{-1} S(h_{1,3}) h_2 \otimes h_{1,2}.v_0  \\ 
=  h_1 v_{-1} S(h_3) h_4 \otimes h_2.v_0 \\
=   h_1 v_{-1} \epsilon(h_3) \otimes h_2.v_0 \\ 
= h_1 v_{-1} \otimes \epsilon(h_3) h_2.v_0 \\
= h_1 v_{-1} \otimes h_2.v_0 $$